# How to use AWS generated password to create IAM user on AWS CLI properly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I wrote a script to: 1) generate random password 2) create new IAM user 3) set up login profile for that user using the generated password.
Below is my code in bash:

```
RANDOM_PASS=$(aws secretsmanager get-random-password --include-space --password-length 20 --require-each-included-type | jq '.RandomPassword' | tr -d '"')

aws iam create-user --user-name $USERID
aws iam create-login-profile --user-name $USERID --password $RANDOM_PASS --password-reset-required
```

as you can see, I used jq to get that specific password string and then truncated the " so I can put it in the create-login-profile.  But it doesn't look very elegant and I feel there must be a better way to do this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need JQ there at all in fact.

Instead of:

```
aws secretsmanager get-random-password --include-space --password-length 20 \
  --require-each-included-type | jq '.RandomPassword' | tr -d '"'
```

You just need:

```
aws secretsmanager get-random-password --include-space --password-length 20 \
  --require-each-included-type --output text
```

AWS CLI commands allow you to switch between JSON and text (and table) output by passing the `--output` switch.

As for general readability of your script, I also try to avoid long lines, so I would refactor as something like:

```
RANDOM_PASS=$(aws secretsmanager get-random-password \
  --require-each-included-type \
  --password-length 20 \
  --include-space \
  --output text)

aws iam create-user --user-name $USERID

aws iam create-login-profile \ 
  --user-name $USERID \
  --password $RANDOM_PASS \
  --password-reset-required
```

It's just a personal preference obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Rewite this part:

`jq '.RandomPassword' | tr -d '"')`

To:

`jq -r '.RandomPassword'`

The `-r` means output raw without the quotes.